# Find 1 year ago from current DateTime

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime

I want to perform this date check:

The date entered by the user **should not be less than** 12 months ago from the current date, e.g.

`if date_value > '03-apr-2009'`

How do I write .NET code to do this?

EDIT:

date_value which i'm entering is in string format

[ as i did casting already as
*( (System.DateTime)date_value).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")* ]

so now i want to make a comparision with this string (date_value) and DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))

so can two strings be compared as such ???? (if one date value is > than the other)

OR Should i do any casting for the comparision ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following code?

```
if(date_value > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
{
    //enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)